# Use line break in JSON inside a shell script

Tags: shell-script

How to use a line break(inside propertyVar) for the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
#Shell script for running the script from Jenkins
#Performance Engineering Team

HealthPollingInterval=$1
ThinkTime=$2
XMLReport=$3
UserDataFile=$4
CdnUrl=$5
StreamingUrl=$6
TrThinkTime=$7
TrMinThinkTime=$8
TrMaxThinkTime=$9
AxThinkTime=$10
AxMinThinkTime=$11
AxMaxThinkTime=$12

triggerPerformanceTest(){
echo "checking the status of the health service"    
HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://localhost/health)
HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
if [ $HTTP_STATUS -eq 200  ] && [ $HTTP_BODY = "OK" ]; then
    propertyVar='{"HealthPollingInterval": '"$HealthPollingInterval"', "ThinkTime": '"$ThinkTime"', "XMLReport": '\""$XMLReport"\"',\r\n
                "UserDataFile": '\""$UserDataFile"\"',  "CdnUrl": '\""$CdnUrl"\"',  "StreamingUrl": '\""$StreamingUrl"\"',
                "TrThinkTime": '"$TrThinkTime"', "TrMinThinkTime": '"$TrMinThinkTime"', "TrMaxThinkTime": '"$TrMaxThinkTime"',
                "AxThinkTime": '"$AxThinkTime"', "AxMinThinkTime": '"$AxMinThinkTime"', "AxMaxThinkTime": '"$AxMaxThinkTime"'}'
    echo "$propertyVar"
    #curl -X POST http://localhost/triggerExecutionwithParamater -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "$propertyVar"
else
    echo "Need to start the service on the target machine"
fi
}
triggerPerformanceTest $HealthPollingInterval $ThinkTime $XMLReport $UserDataFile $CdnUrl $StreamingUrl $TrThinkTime $TrMinThinkTime $TrMaxThinkTime $AxThinkTime $AxMinThinkTime $AxMaxThinkTime
```

Inside the propertyVar there are 10-15 variables If I keep them in one line the script is working fine. But I want to keep them orderly using a line break.
Used \, \n, "\n" , '\n', \r\n so far and nothing get worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to [use heredoc to preserve formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash), alhough [heredoc delimeter must be without quotes to perform substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc)

So in your case the block between then... and ..else will be

```
    read -r -d '' propertyVar <<EOF
        {
            "HealthPollingInterval": "$HealthPollingInterval", "ThinkTime": "$ThinkTime", "XMLReport": "$XMLReport"
            "UserDataFile": "$UserDataFile",  "CdnUrl": "$CdnUrl",  "StreamingUrl": "$StreamingUrl",
            "TrThinkTime": "$TrThinkTime", "TrMinThinkTime": "$TrMinThinkTime", "TrMaxThinkTime": "$TrMaxThinkTime",
            "AxThinkTime": "$AxThinkTime", "AxMinThinkTime": "$AxMinThinkTime", "AxMaxThinkTime": "$AxMaxThinkTime"
        }
    EOF
    echo "$propertyVar"
```

If you will specify `<<'EOF'` or `<<"EOF"`, no variable substitution will be done inside the  heredoc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create valid JSON is with a JSON-aware tool, such as `jq`.

The following creates the JSON document given the 12 command line arguments given to the script, and posts the document using `curl`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 12 ]; then
        printf 'Expected 12 arguments, got %d\n' "$#"
        exit 1
fi >&2

args=( "$@" )   # Save the original arguments for later.

# Prepare arguments for "jq".
for param in \
        HealthPollingInterval \
        ThinkTime \
        XMLReport \
        UserDataFile \
        CdnUrl \
        StreamingUrl \
        TrThinkTime \
        TrMinThinkTime \
        TrMaxThinkTime \
        AxThinkTime \
        AxMinThinkTime \
        AxMaxThinkTime
do
        set -- "$@" --arg "$param" "$1"
        shift
done

# Create our JSON document and post it.
# Output an error message and terminate if the post fails.
if ! jq -nc "$@" '$ARGS.named' |
        curl --silent --show-error --fail \
                --json @- 'http://localhost/triggerExecutionwithParamater'
then
        echo 'Failed to post JSON document.' >&2
        exit 1
fi


# Call triggerPerformanceTest with the original arguments.
triggerPerformanceTest "${args[@]}"
```

This uses a loop to create a series of `--arg key value` arguments later used with `jq`.  The `jq` call creates a JSON object containing the named keys and their values, and this is then piped to `curl` and posted to the API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Kusalananda's, using `perl` instead of `jq`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
perl -CA -MJSON -le '
  $object{$_} = shift @ARGV for qw(
    HealthPollingInterval  ThinkTime         XMLReport
    UserDataFile           CdnUrl            StreamingUrl
    TrThinkTime            TrMinThinkTime    TrMaxThinkTime
    AxThinkTime            AxMinThinkTime    AxMaxThinkTime
  );
  print encode_json(\%object)' -- "$@" |
  curl --silent --show-error --fail \
      --json @- 'http://localhost/triggerExecutionwithParamater'
```